# Update value of column in database using checkboxlist in vb.net window forms

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, checkboxlist

I Have this Lines of codes:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CBL.Items.Count
    If CBL.Items(i).Selected Then
        If i = 0 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set Picture = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 1 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set BCertificate = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 2 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set DTest = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 3 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set XRay = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 4 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set MCertificate = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 5 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set BClearance = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 6 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set PNClearance = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 7 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set DLicense = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If

    End If
Next
```

I encounter the error: Public member 'Selected' on type 'String' not found..

I have this codes on the form load:

```
CBL.Items.Add("Picture")
CBL.Items.Add("Birth Certificate")
CBL.Items.Add("Drug Test")
CBL.Items.Add("X-Ray")
CBL.Items.Add("Medical Certificate")
CBL.Items.Add("Barangay Clearance")
CBL.Items.Add("Police/NBI Clearance")
CBL.Items.Add("Drivers License for Drivers")
```

I just this: "I created a loop for all the items, and If the checkbox is checked, then the index of that item is again passed to an if condition where the index of that item is equal to the sql statement.
Any help please..

Answer (score 0):

I assume CBL is a CheckedListBox. If so, CBL.Items(i) does not have a `Selected` property. You can use `CheckState` property instead.

Comment: Can i use this one instead? If CBL.SelectedItems(i) Then

Comment: i still receive and error even though i used`CBL.SelectedItems(i)` i get this one Conversion from string "X-Ray" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CBL.Items.Count - 1
    If CBL.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then

       //TODO YOU CODE
       If i = 0 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set Picture = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 1 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set BCertificate = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 2 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set DTest = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 3 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set XRay = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 4 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set MCertificate = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 5 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set BClearance = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 6 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set PNClearance = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
        If i = 7 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set DLicense = 'Ok' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' ,MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If

    End If
Next
```